# Sprite not visible

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm making an HTML5 game in Easeljs. The problem is: the sprite doesn't show.
What am I doing wrong?
Sprite code:

```
function Sprite () {
    this.createHoofdpersonage();
}
Sprite.prototype.createHoofdpersonage = function() {    
    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        "images" : ["images/game/Hoofdpersonage.png"],
        "frames" : {"regX":0,"height":57,"width":40,"regY":0, "count":5},
        "animations" : {
            "stand": 0,
            "runForwards": [1,2, "stand"],
            "runBackwards": [3,4,"stand"]//return to stand      
        },
    });
    this.hoofdpersonage = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "stand");
};
Sprite.prototype.getHoofdpersonage = function() {
    return this.hoofdpersonage;
};
```

Adding the sprite:

```
sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.getHoofdpersonage().y = canvas.height;
sprite.getHoofdpersonage().x = canvas.width/4;
//add to stage
stage.addChild(street,sprite.getHoofdpersonage());
stage.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only updating the stage one time (in the function above), then nothing will show because the image has not yet loaded. If you put Ticker.tick listener on the stage (even just for testing), it will probably show up after a frame or two.

I recommend preloading the image first. Something like this:

```
function Sprite () {
    this.loadImage();
}

Sprite.prototype.loadImage = function() {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = this.createHoofdpersonage.bind(this); // To keep scope. will not work in all browsers, but shows you how it should work.
    this.image.src = "images/game/Hoofdpersonage.png";
}
Sprite.prototype.createHoofdpersonage = function() {    
    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        "images" : [this.image],
        "frames" : {"regX":0,"height":57,"width":40,"regY":0, "count":5},
        "animations" : {
            "stand": 0,
            "runForwards": [1,2, "stand"],
            "runBackwards": [3,4,"stand"]//return to stand      
        },
    });
    this.hoofdpersonage = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "stand");
};
Sprite.prototype.getHoofdpersonage = function() {
    return this.hoofdpersonage;
};
```

Comment: I chaged the code to preloadjs, so normally the problem that the image is still unloaded should be solved. Unfortunately nothing appears. So I looked at the code that is updating the stage (Ticker):
  `var updateStage = function(event){
  console.log(sprite.getHoofdpersonage().currentAnimation);
  if(!event.paused){
   if(moveBackgroundLeft) images['street'].x -= 5;
   if(moveBackgroundRight) images['street'].x += 5;
   backgroundMoveBackIntoCanvas();
   stage.update();
  }
 }
 initTimer = function() {
  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",updateStage);
 }`

Comment: Any chance you can post a sample?

Comment: You can find the code [here](https://github.com/javalSoft/javalSoft.github.io/tree/master/js) and a "working" example [here](http://javalsoft.github.io/)

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the console? I grabbed your sprite code, and put it in a fiddle, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/kqyo3pgg/

Comment: No, I've no errors in the console. Not in firefox and not in chrome. I think that the sprite is loaded in the background, but simply doesn't show up.